# How in in laravel/Inertiajs to show custom template for 503?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

How can I catch in laravel 9/Inertiajs 3 and show custom message for 503 error,
which is triggered by

```
 php artisan down
```

command.

I created page

```
resources/js/Pages/503.vue
```

But is is not shown for my site...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://inertiajs.com/error-handling

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the view as [the documentation suggests](https://laravel.com/docs/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

```
resources/views/errors/503.blade.php
```

You can still use a vue component inside that view, but that's the file that should be present.

Comment: In my resources/views/app.blade.php I have line :
    <body >
        @inertia
    </body>

as resources/views/errors/503.blade.php is php file how can I show custom vuejs components on 503.blade.php ?